# jQuery mobile - pagecontainerload event ui parameter empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
$('body').pagecontainer({
    load : function(a,jq){
        console.log($.isEmptyObject(jq))
    }
});
```

Returns `true`. That definitely shouldn't be the case, according to [the documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-load)

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Make sure you load an external page http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7m3mfbn7/ http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/

Comment: Hi Omar, your JSfiddle doesn't seem to be working. I've noticed this is a bug that the JQM team are aware. Big fan of your blog btw!

Comment: Im not sure whether it's a bug, the documentation doesn't explain the proper way of binding pagecontainer events. I'll get you with another detailed example. I'm glad you liked my blog :)

Comment: btw, I forgot to add `/show` at the end of demo link http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7m3mfbn7/show

Comment: Looks like a bug in [1.4.3](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wtyhc7nw/show/). Working for [1.4.2](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7m3mfbn7/show)